# PhoneGap support for ads

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, mobile, cordova

I'm planning on building all the major platforms using PhoneGap.  I know iPhone has iAds, and there's others for android, etc.  When it comes to building a PhoneGap application, is there  one common advertising platform that will have to be used, or is there a way to incorporate one of the native features for ads?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to  implement adWhirl, it's a great service and is compitable for all kinds of mobile platforms.

[go to adwhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/)

Comment: That looks promising, i'll have to check that out.  Thanks.